# How can I control push notification ON/OFF according to conditions? in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am making a push notification feature using reactnative push notification.
If I create a channel according to the reactnative push notification official statement, I can control it only when I enter the notification category in the application information of the application.
Can I use the reactnative push notifictaion library to control when I create a component within the app like Youtubemusic (below Image) and implement the push setting ON OFF control function? It doesn't seem to be in the official documentation.
I'm trying to implement this feature within the app, but I'm curious about how it's implemented in practice!

i'm not using local notification just remote

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have 2 way to achieve this: on backend side or on frontend side.

###### Backend

Send to backend current state of toggle settings inside your app. When backend want to send push to client, it is internally checks state of this toggle and make a decision send or not.

###### Frontend

All your push notifications must be send as `data` only and with high priority (`contentAvailable: true`, `priority: 'high'`).
After that, only mobile app will control showing of push notifications, because `data` only push not display anything, just trigger mobile app about new message.

So, when your frontend app receive new push message, it check current user settings and make decision display it or not.